# Linux boot loader

Tags: linux, bootloader

I'm trying to boot Linux on a GPS device from a SD card.

I have found some informations about the device on Internet and apparently it's possible to load a customized Windows CE.

To achieve this, they use a boot loader file that has the extention ".bld"

I extracted the ISO of Ubuntu MID on the SD card, but there is no files with a bld extension. I guess it use a different boot loader system .. which doesn't seem to work on the device.

So my question is;

Is there a way to use a "bld" file to boot Linux ? If so, how can I create the file ?

I'm sorry if the question is stupid or off-track, I don't know much about boot loaders ..

In case you wonder, here's the device:

http://www.curtisint.com/web/browser.asp?productID=GPD359&catName=GLOBAL%20POSITIONING%20SYSTEM

More detailed specs (and mod site):

http://gpd359.wikidot.com/article:outofbox

Edit: Turns out I only had to put a file named "YFGo2CE.bld" (the file only contains a random string) on the SD card and reset the device. From there I can boot directly in WindowsCE and load the suggested Haret ROM tool.

Thanks!

Comment: This does not belong on superuser

Comment: Did you try dd'ing the iso directly to the sd card? That should reproduce the boot sector correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you might want to look at is the Haret ROM tool. [It can be found and more information here](http://handhelds.org/moin/moin.cgi/FrontPage?action=show&redirect=StartSeite)